# Clingo cannot access certain files

Tags: clingo

I am working with Clingo for the first time and followed the given installation instructions using miniconda. I do have a working environment, but it only works in a single folder and I am not sure why. I am ultimately trying to get it to work in my local GitHub repository, but any file I try to run outside of a specific folder on my computer returns an error. Below is an screenshot; the first command was an attempt in a new folder while the second attempt is in the only folder that works.

[image: Clingo Issue]

I am investigating the best I can, but I am a novice. My best guess is the folder it works in is the only working directory. How to change my working directory I cannot find though.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed clingo in your base conda environment (which from the screenshots I infer you probably did) you should be able to access it from anywhere given that the base environment is active.

Possible culprits can be:

- there is no file `test2.lp` at your `C:\Users\<your username>\`
- your `test2.lp` has wrong syntax.

The latter option seems less likely, because I think clingo would specify where your syntax error precisely is (and it is not doing that), but you could also check it.